# NULL values and "0" strings in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, null

I'm having trouble adding a `"0"` string to a list of strings in C.

With my current code, I'm having trouble distinguishing between a `NULL` value and a `"0"` with my current code. I have tried to debug with the if statement `(if(pch == "0"))` but when I'm outputting it doesn't go into the if statement.

```
          printf("%c\n",next_line[0]);
          pch = strtok(next_line,",");
          printf("%s\n",pch);
          if(pch == "0"){
            printf("NULL VALUE");
            strcpy(strs[i],pch);
            i++;
            pch = strtok(NULL, ",");
          }
          while(pch != NULL){
            strcpy(strs[i],pch);
            i++;
            pch = strtok(NULL, ",");
          }
          //go on to print values
```

the input is: `0,1,03:48:13,9` 
I never make it past the first character. What can I do to keep my code? Can I maybe change

```
     pch = strtok(NULL, ","); 
    to pch = strtok(SOMEOTHERVALUE, ",");?
```

Comment: you want to check with `null` or `zero`?

Comment: I want to copy the comma separated values above ( 0,1,03:48:13,9) into an array (strs). I'm having trouble with CSVs that start with 0. CSV's that don't have 0s (which equal `NULL` in C) work fine.

Comment: Why would you compare with the literal digit "0" if you're checking for a null value? It's impossible for us to figure out what's wrong with your code because you've given us no idea what it's supposed to do. It seems you want to check for a NULL (no string at all), and then copy? If there's no string because the pointer is NULL, what's to copy?

Comment: Hint: what does `==` do? It tells you if two things are equal. What is `pch`? It's a pointer to a part of the line. What is `"0"`? It's a pointer to a constant string "0". What happens when you compare pointers with `==`?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with NULL as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot able to check like this,

```
if(pch == "0"){
 ...
}
```

pch is pointer. You are comparing that with a string. So you have to make that as like this,

```
if ( *pch == '0' ) { 
 ...
}
```

Or else do like this,

```
if ( strcmp(pch,"0") == 0 ) {
 ...
}
```

It will help you to check the `zero` in a character string.

Comment: Ah I see... Thank you. Now when I'm adding that to the array of strings should I use the * notation for pch too?

Comment: if you are using `strcpy` then there is no need to give that.